# Is there a way to change padding of content at mobile in content Builder?

Tags: marketing-cloud, html, content

I have an email I am creating in content builder and I cannot change the padding in layout settings at the MOBILE level to whatever i want.  I know this can be done using custom HTML, but is there a way to make it as user friendly as possible by doing it in the interface?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very generic. I will try to answer in scenarios:

If you want to edit the padding for mobile in terms of template. Then you can go to `Emails > Design Tab > Mobile Styles > You can choose the padding from interface.`

Below is the screenshot of it:

[image]

If you want to edit the padding for some blocks, then go to the `blocks > HTML Tab` and then try to use `!important` in In-line css for padding.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks I will test it out.  To be more specific - in different content blocks I want to have different padding in Mobile vs desktop.  I did see the mobile toggle but the problem is if I change padding at the mobile level it also stays the same at desktop.  I was wondering if it was possible to do this inside the UI instead of coding up HTML

Comment: I gave it a shot.  The thing is this mobile styles applies to the outer table at the mobile level so it essentially pushes the whole email to the side instead of adding ONLY padding to the body text inside the block to have less spacing between the text and the "wall" at mobile level

Comment: Yes @GS65, the mobile styles will be applicable to the whole template.As i mentioned in answer for the individual blocks try to overwrite the default css with !important property in HTML tab (overwrite with padding). This needs to be done in HTML and can't be done in UI.